# is there any need to wear LANGOT(Loin Cloth) while doing gym workout

Tags: exercise, workout, gym, hernia

Here in India, lot of people doing workout in gym wear LANGOT(Loin Cloth or Drawers or Nappy), e.g. [image]   [image]

They say that if they don't wear it, they will suffer from Hernia.
 I have joined gym some days ago and everyone in the gym use it and also advice me to use it or I will get hernia. But I don't think that wearing it will prevent me from hernia.
So is there any need to wear that while doing workout in gym?

Comment: If it prevented hernias, then a lot of people in the Sates, and other counties, would be getting hernias.  It's just another gym myth.

Comment: You need to wear tight underwear while lifting heavy weights and hence this ritual of wearing langot. But the same can be done wearing a tight brief.

Comment: @PravinCG can you please explain what is the need of wearing tight underwear while lifting heavy weights, whether is it only to prevent external accidental injuries or there is any other reason

Comment: I'm with @DForck42.  I live in the US.  This is not something American weight lifters do (don't wear this restrictive garment, and also don't go out of their way to wear briefs, or other tight underwear).  I'm not the right person to write a bio-mechanical explaination of why they wouldn't help.  If you want to avoid hernias, make sure that you're lifting appropriate amounts of weight.

Comment: If this were about running, I'd say the support is helpful, but weightlifting doesn't really require special clothing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is no need to wear it. [It doesn't prevent a hernia](http://www.drmirkin.com/fitness/7730.htm).

Even one doctor told me once not to wear it, because the testicles are held too close to the body. It is not good because when our body temperature rises, they need to stay away from body. While doing workout our body temperature rises greatly so it's bad to wear it during workout.

Comment: I'd like to see more credible reference, but in this case I think the one who makes the claim (that it prevents hermia) is more obliged to provide some first.

Answer (score 1):

it is important to wear this while exercising. you never know what movement will cause a problem."Langot" has been used by wrestlers for as long as the sport has been on earth. If you are over weight (even a little) and using your own body weight for training and doing movements like squats, push ups and/or other leg movements, or anything that puts pressure ofyour abdominal muscles, it can trigger Hernia or other issues with your reproductive system.

Doctors will always tell you things to make you not "worry". They will not be held accountable if something happens. Do you think you can argue with the doctor with "you said it". ????

So take precaution by wearing langot or buy a supporter from a sports shop.

Be safe. Cheers.

Comment: There are no wrestlers that I know of in the US that wear a langot. Most wear singlets with protective cups. A langot will NOT prevent issues with hernias or the reproductive system.

Comment: WHat a stupid comment, langot and supporter are same thing. Just different versions. Even wrestlers in India or other countries do not wear langot they wear supporter. Both are kind of underpants, both does the job of supporting your testicles, one you have to tie (langot) another comes with elastic you don't have to tie just wear it as it is (supporter)

Comment: I am giving upvote because it is the right answer. Supporter (may be of any kind i.e. langot or tights with cup)is mandatory to wear otherwise you would face problems like ED, Hernia, constipation, if not now than later when you are in phase of lifting/push/pull heavy weights. If not, then why people across the world using it.